# Are there any methods in Laravel that automatically add a model to an authenticated user?

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent

I find myself doing this frequently:

```
$model→user()→save(Auth::user());
```

This requires importing the Auth facade into every controllers where the relationship is being saved.

I was thinking of possibly create a simple method (saveWithAuthUser()) under User model to save the authenticated user.

Just wondering if this already exists as a Laravel method already or not, and if not, is this a pointless idea?

Comment: why would this be a method on the User model?

Comment: So I can use it multiple models without duplicating code (i.e. $model→user()->saveWithAuthUser()).

Comment: if `user()` is a relationship method that doesn't return a model, and second if you did get a User model instance how would it know what model you are trying to save to what relationship? ... so why would this method be on the User and not the other models

Comment: Ah, I see - I guess this won't work.

Comment: just need to think about it more, but you could listen for model events and then see if there is an authenticated user and assign the user potentially, if that meets all needs

Comment: What about creating it as a global helper method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This requires importing the Auth facade into every controllers where
>   the relationship is being saved.

You can avoid this by getting the user from the `Request` instead.

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $model->user()->associate($request->user());
}
```

There is also a global helper for exactly this.

```
$user = auth()->user();
```